# Manage GetFileSystemEntries dir Errors Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using GetFileSystemEntries() in visual basic to get a complete structure of a drive, I used the exceptions that I found in MSDN for the errors but I can't figure out how to just pass the directories that give me errors and save the others in my array.

This is my code:

```
Dim array()

    Try
        array = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        For Each x As System.String In array
            list_Drives.Items.Add(x)
        Next
    Catch exp As UnauthorizedAccessException
        System.Console.WriteLine("I don't have permission here")

    Catch exp As ArgumentNullException
        System.Console.WriteLine("Path is a null reference.")
    Catch exp As System.Security.SecurityException
        System.Console.WriteLine("The caller does not have the " + _
                                "required permission.")
    Catch exp As ArgumentException
        System.Console.WriteLine("Path is an empty string, " + _
                                "contains only white spaces, " + _
                                "or contains invalid characters.")
    Catch exp As System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        System.Console.WriteLine("The path encapsulated in the " + _
                                "Directory object does not exist.")
    End Try
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown by `System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries`, so when this happens, the for-loop does not execute and there are no "other" directories (unless there's some other code you're not showing).

If you want to recursively enumerate directories starting at the root, then you might be best off writing your own recursive code. This would allow you to skip over exceptions (i.e., directory which you are not allowed to enumerate).

Uinsg `GetFileSystemEntries` with the `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` parameter is better suited for traversing directory structure that's created by your application.  Otherwise, when traversing arbitrary directories, it's quite possible that you will run into access issues.  Also, if there's a link in the directory structure that creates a loop [Microsoft says you'll end up in an infinite loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you create your own traversal algorithm, you can avoid these problem.  Alternatively, if you look around, you might find a library that already does this for you.

Comment: I don't have any other code, This code is inside a button, when I used `System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\")` all works ok and my listbox gets filled. but just with the root dirs

Comment: So you're not getting an exception?

Comment: By the way, you should escape the backslash: `"C:\\"`

Comment: Not, when I use:
 `Dim array()

        array = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("C:\")
        For Each x As System.String In array
            list_Drives.Items.Add(x)
        Next`

I don't get any exceptions. 

The exception is occurring when the code is trying to enter to some dir inside the Recycle Bin dir. `UnauthorizedAccessException`

(Should I necessarily escape the backslash? because isn't given me any errors.)

Comment: @jdigital: Not in VB.

Comment: If you want to recursively enumerate directories starting at the root, then you might be best off writing your own recursive code.  This would allow you to skip over exceptions (i.e., directory which you are not allowed to enumerate).

Comment: I see, then I will have think in another way to get the file and dir structure.

Thank